# Trim a trailing .0

Tags: ruby, excel, ruby-2.0, roo-gem

I have an Excel column containing part numbers. Here is a sample

[image]

As you can see, it can be many different datatypes: `Float`, `Int`, and `String`. I am using `roo` gem to read the file. The problem is that `roo` interprets integer cells as `Float`, adding a trailing zero to them (16431 => 16431.0). I want to trim this trailing zero. I cannot use `to_i` because it will trim all the trailing numbers of the cells that require a decimal in them (the first row in the above example) and will cut everything after a string char in the `String` rows (the last row in the above example).

Currently, I have a a method that checks the last two characters of the cell and trims them if they are ".0"

```
def trim(row)
    if row[0].to_s[-2..-1] == ".0"
        row[0] = row[0].to_s[0..-3]
    end
end
```

This works, but it feels terrible and hacky. What is the proper way of getting my Excel file contents into a Ruby data structure?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
def trim num
  i, f = num.to_i, num.to_f
  i == f ? i : f
end

trim(2.5) # => 2.5
trim(23) # => 23
```

or, from string:

```
def convert x
  Float(x)
  i, f = x.to_i, x.to_f
  i == f ? i : f
rescue ArgumentError
  x
end

convert("fjf") # => "fjf"
convert("2.5") # => 2.5
convert("23") # => 23
convert("2.0") # => 2
convert("1.00") # => 1
convert("1.10") # => 1.1
```

Comment: or just result = result.to_i if result == result.to_i

Answer (score 37):

For those using Rails, ActionView has the `number_with_precision` method that takes a `strip_insignificant_zeros: true` argument to handle this.

```
number_with_precision(13.00, precision: 2,  strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
# => 13
number_with_precision(13.25, precision: 2,  strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
# => 13.25
```

See the [`number_with_precision`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) documentation for more information.

Comment: Good solution for those specifically using Rails

Answer (score 3):

This should cover your needs in most cases: `some_value.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')`.

It trims all trailing zeroes and a decimal point followed only by zeroes. Otherwise, it leaves the string alone.

It's also very performant, as it is entirely string-based, requiring no floating point or integer conversions, assuming your input value is already a string:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.19)
irb(main):001:0> '123.0'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "123"
irb(main):002:0> '123.000'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "123"
irb(main):003:0> '123.560'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "123.560"
irb(main):004:0> '123.'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "123."
irb(main):005:0> '123'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "123"
irb(main):006:0> '100'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "100"
irb(main):007:0> '127.0.0.1'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "127.0.0.1"
irb(main):008:0> '123xzy45'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "123xzy45"
irb(main):009:0> '123xzy45.0'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "123xzy45"
irb(main):010:0> 'Bobby McGee'.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')
=> "Bobby McGee"
irb(main):011:0>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I'd just add to cast a float to string first: `some_value.to_s.gsub(/(\.)0+$/, '')`

Answer (score -1):

[Numeric values are returned as type :float](http://roo.rubyforge.org/)

```
def convert_cell(cell)
  if cell.is_a?(Float)
    i = cell.to_i
    cell == i.to_f ? i : cell
  else
    cell
  end
end

convert_cell("foobar") # => "foobar"
convert_cell(123) # => 123
convert_cell(123.4) # => 123.4
```

Comment: That is the same as the first part of my answer, except that you do not do memoization.

Comment: correct. didn't see it when I started writing.
Edited it now.

Comment: `convert_string("1.00") # => "1.00"`, `convert_string("1.20") # => "1.20"`

Comment: edited again. it should just return whatever the actual value of the cell is.