# Ruby code to remove insignificant decimal places?

Tags: ruby, string, decimal, precision, rational-number

I would like to get an elegant code, which removes the insignificant closing zeroes, eg:

```
29.970 => 29.97
29.97 => 29.97
25.00 => 25
25.0 => 25
```

I tried:

```
argument.to_r.to_f.to_s
```

But doesn't work in every cases, eg on 25.00 gives 25.0

Comment: Did you try [this `convert` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18533211/1241782)? It works for the 4 cases you provided.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Trailing zeros are only significant when the number is a string:

```
def strip_trailing_zero(n)
  n.to_s.sub(/\.0+$/, '')
end

strip_trailing_zero(29.970) # => "29.97"
strip_trailing_zero(29.97)  # => "29.97"
strip_trailing_zero(25.00)  # => "25"
strip_trailing_zero(25.0)   # => "25"
strip_trailing_zero(250)   # => "250"
```

This converts the incoming floating point numbers and converts them into a string, then uses a simple `sub` search and replace to trim the trailing `0` and optionally the decimal point.

You can figure out how to convert them back to integers and floats if that's necessary. This will remove significant trailing zeros if you pass a integer/fixnum. How to guard against that is also something for you to figure out.

Comment: if you pass it integer then it will also remove 0 from an integer value, so don't pass it integer values
"20" => 2

Comment: Since the point was to remove trailing zeroes from floating point then it shouldn't get passed an integer. It'd be an easy thing to protect against though.

Comment: You need to remove the question mark from regex
n.to_s.sub(/\.0+$/, '')

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK
strip_trailing_zero(250) => "25"

Comment: It did when the question was asked and answered. Ruby has changed.

Comment: If you are working with rails, you may check the `number_with_precision` method from ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper

Comment: @theTinMan: Ruby hasn't changed. The regex, `/\.?0+$/` says "Maybe there's a `.`, maybe not, followed by one or more 0." Your replacement would turn `"250"` (Not a `.`, but one `0`) into `"25"` in any language.

Answer (score 8):

Try `sprintf('%g', value_here)` ?

```
`g` ->  Convert a floating point number using exponential form
  | if the exponent is less than -4 or greater than or
  | equal to the precision, or in dd.dddd form otherwise.

https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf

sprintf('%g',29.970) # => "29.97"
sprintf('%g',29.97)  # => "29.97"
sprintf('%g',25.00)  # => "25"
sprintf('%g',25.0)   # => "25"
```

Comment: 0 comes to -0 with %g

Comment: Be careful! It looks like it works but if you pass 21385524.0031 You'll get: 2.13855e+07